# Images generated from the same array are different during image compression

Tags: python, image, numpy, testing, python-imaging-library

In this code sample, the assertion in the function fails.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import PIL.Image


def make_images(tmp_path):
    np.random.seed(0)
    shape = (4, 6, 3)
    rgb = np.random.randint(0, 256, shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    test_image = PIL.Image.fromarray(rgb)
    image_path = tmp_path / 'test_image.jpg'
    test_image.save(image_path)
    return image_path, rgb


def test_Image_load_rgb(tmp_path):
    image_path, original_rgb = make_images(tmp_path)
    rgb2 = np.array(PIL.Image.open(image_path))
    assert np.array_equal(rgb2, original_rgb)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_Image_load_rgb(tmp_path)
```

When I look at the two arrays, `original_rgb` and `rgb2`, they have different values, so of course it is failing, but I don't understand why their arrays have different values.

Opening them both as images using `PIL.Image.fromarray()`, visually they look similar but not the same, the brightness values are slightly altered, visually.

I don't understand why this is.

The two images are:
[image: test_image.jpg]
[image: test_image2.jpg]

Note: This is fails the same way for both pytest and when run as a script.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me to test this with BMP and PNG images, and this problem does not happen with them.

So it occurs to me that the JPG Compression process somehow alters the data slightly, since it is lossy compression.

But I was surprised, that it would have an effect in such a small and light image.

I am leaving this question in case someone else stumbles on to this.

Anyone offering a more detailed explanation would be great!

UPDATE: I noticed the colors in BMP/PNG are much different from the JPG. Any reason why?